dependency injection for generic command handlers
I have a Command with this definition:
public record GetEnumQuery<TEnum>(
    ) : IBaseCommandQuery<IList<EnumViewModel>>
     where TEnum : Enum;

and a handler with this deinition:
public class GetEnumQueryHandler<TEnum> : IBaseCommandQueryHandler<GetEnumQuery<TEnum>, IList<EnumViewModel>>
    where TEnum : Enum

how to inject it? I want inject in a way that for all handlers with different enums it can be usable.

If you're using Mediator package then this does the job for you: services.AddMediatR(cfg =>      cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(GetEnumQuery).Assembly));

@sa-es-ir I am using MediatR and I tries the code you wrote but it didn't work
